# html required only apply to one form

Tags: html

I have an html page with two forms, one for signup and one for login, i have made all fields required, but i want to make it so, the signup fields only are required, when you sign up, and the login fields only are required one you login.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<body>
<form name="register" action="FrontController" method="POST" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
 <div class="container">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
     <hr>

<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

<label for="email"><b>Postnummer</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit postnummer" name="postnummer" required>

<label for="email"><b>Postnummer</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit postnummer" name="postnummer" required>

<label for="email"><b>Adresse</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv din adresse" name="adresse" required>

<label for="email"><b>Telefonnummer</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit telefonnummer" name="phonenr" required>

<label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

<label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
</label>


<div class="container">
<h1>Login</h1>
<hr>

<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

<label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>


<p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

<div class="clearfix">
  <button type="submit" class="loginbtn" value="Submit">Login</button>
  <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" value ="Submit">Login</button>
</div>
```

Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both submit buttons under same form so that validation is required. Use different form for login and signup.

```html
<form>
Login form 
<input type="text" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>


<form>
Register form 
<input type="text" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two separate `form`s to achieve what you want,
as the `required` property only applies to the current `form`.

Here is your HTML modified:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="register" action="FrontController" method="POST" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
      <label for="email"><b>Postnummer</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit postnummer" name="postnummer" required>
      <label for="email"><b>Postnummer</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit postnummer" name="postnummer" required>
      <label for="email"><b>Adresse</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv din adresse" name="adresse" required>
      <label for="email"><b>Telefonnummer</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit telefonnummer" name="phonenr" required>
      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
      <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me</label>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" value="Submit">Sign-up</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="login" action="FrontController" method="POST" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="loginbtn" value="Submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.